# Determine stability of the equilibrium of $\dot x=f(x)$ in terms of the derivatives of $f$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Let $ f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} $ be $C^∞$ suppose the following:

1. $f(0) = 0,$
2. There is a smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}  $ so that $f^{n}(0) \neq 0$

Determine stability of the equilibrium at $0$ for the differential equation $ \dot x = f(x) $ in terms of $n$ and the
sign of $f^{n}(0)$.

---

The exercise sheet provides a hint: Use Taylor’s theorem:
$$\dot x = \left( \frac {f^{n}(x)}{n!} + xh(x)  \right) x^{n}$$

The problem is the $h$ is not definied (there is a reference to a page in the book for $h$, but the page is wrong!)

Any suggestion on how to proceed? even without using the given hint?

Comment: Maybe following the hint might give an idea? What is the Taylor expansion of $f$ and what might $h$ be?

Comment: A consequences of Taylor's theorem I have: the behavior of $f$ near $x_0$ is dominated by the term ${f^{(n)}(x)}(x)^n$, and the sign of $f (x)$ is equal to the sign of $f^{(n)}(x)(x)^n$ for all $x$ sufficiently close to $x_0$. So  could just study the sign of $f^{(n)}(x)$, but how i envolved $n$?
.

Answer (score 1):

This is more transparent if you think of the [phase line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_line_(mathematics)). What actually determines stability is not the derivatives of $f$ per se, but the sign of $f$ on both sides of the equilibrium point.

[image: Image from Wikipedia article linked above]

- If $f$ changes sign from positive to negative, the equilibrium is stable. (The arrows on phase line are toward the equilibrium)
- If $f$ changes sign from negative to positive, the equilibrium is unstable. (The arrows point away from equilibrium)
- If $f$ does not change the sign, the equilibrium is semi-stable. (Arrows point toward it on one side, and away on the other.)

The Taylor expansion tells us which of three options holds, because in a small neighborhood of a zero $x_0$, the sign of $f$ is determined by the sign of the nonzero term of lowest degree (the other terms are small in comparison to it). So:

- If $n$ is odd and $f^{(n)}(x_0)<0$, the sign goes from positive to negative: stable.
- If $n$ is odd and $f^{(n)}(x_0)>0$, the sign goes from negative to positive: unstable.
- If $n$ is even, the sign is the same on both sides of $x_0$: semi-stable.